# How do I retrieve the value of a lookup-field in a workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, workflow, designer-workflow, lookup-column

I'm very new to SharePoint, and I'm working through understanding lists, workflows, and relationships between the two. I'm working on a SharePoint page to keep track of tasks completed in a timeframe. In my SharePoint site, I have 2 list objects;

- **Timeframe**

  - *ID*
  - *Start Date*
  - *End Date*
- **Task**

  - *Title*
  - *Description*
  - *Timeframe # Completed In* (Lookup field to **Timeframe**.ID)
  - *Lookup: Start Date* (Lookup field to **Timeframe**.Start Date when the *ID*s match)
  - *Lookup: End Date* (Lookup field to **Timeframe**.End Date when the *ID*s match)
  - *Start Date* (Field I want to save the lookup value into)
  - *End Date* (Field I want to save the lookup value into)

I've been creating a workflow that updates **Task**.*Start Date* and **Task**.*End Date* when an item is created or edited AND if **Task**.*Timeframe # Completed In*. First, we check if **Task**.*Sprint # completed In* is not empty. Then, **Task**.*Lookup Start Date* and **Task**.*Lookup End Date* are saved into workflow variables. Finally, we load the variable values into **Task**.*Start Date* and **Task**.*End Date*.

Each time I update a record, the workflow runs but is cancelled by an error. Error message:

*Coercion Failed: Unable to transform the input lookup data into the requested type*

Here's the workflow outline:

```
Step 1:
  if Current Item:Sprint # Completed In  is not empty
    Set Variable: lookupStart to Current Item:Lookup: Sprint Start Date
    then Set Variable: lookupEnd to Current Item:Lookup: Sprint End Date
    then Set Start Date to Variable: lookupStart
    then Set End Date to Variable: lookupEnd
```

How can I accomplish this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The workflow is looking for a Date and Time field, but lookups return text. You need to return the field as Lookup text.

`Set Variable: lookupStart to Current Item:Lookup: Sprint Start Date, Return fields as Lookup Value (as Text)`