# SharePoint Designer Workflow Field Lookup Not Displaying

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, lookup-column, workflow-lookup

I have a SharePoint list called Item Orders. The "Item Name" field is a lookup from a field of the same name on the list Item Definitions. The field "Item Type" from Item Definitions is also displayed on Item Orders from the lookup. I am trying to create a workflow on Item Orders that sends an email when "Item Type" equals "Book".

In SharePoint Designer when using the condition "If any value equals value" the "Item Type" field is not displayed in the "Field from source" dropdown, only "Item Name" is.

Is it possible to trigger an email when an item on Item Orders is created with a specific value of "Item Type"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I retrieve the value of a lookup-field in a workflow?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/187377/how-do-i-retrieve-the-value-of-a-lookup-field-in-a-workflow)

Comment: It seems like that questions had to do with using the wrong field type in the workflow. In my case I can't add the lookup field to the workflow at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may get it from Item Definitions list:

```
Data Source: 'Item Definitions'
Field: 'Item Type'

Search by:
Field: ID
Value: CurrentItem->Item Name (as Lookup id)
```